# SAS IF THEN Statement for Range of Columns

Tags: sas, range, conditional-statements, datastep

I want to create a new column based on a range of columns(GAP1-GAP5). I wanted to use something like this:

```
IF FIND(GAP1-GAP5,'New Start') THEN FILTER_NewStart=1
```

but got an error so had to use this:

```
IF FIND(GAP1,'New Start') OR FIND(GAP2,'New Start') OR FIND(GAP3,'New Start') 
  OR FIND(GAP4,'New Start') OR FIND(GAP5,'New Start') THEN FILTER_NewStart=1;
```

Do I need to use a loop or can I use a function for a range of columns to achieve this?

Comment: An `array` statement will probably work faster than the accepted answer, if speed is of any concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try concatenating them and using `find` on the variable instead.

```
if(find(cat(of GAP1-GAP5), 'New Start') ) then FILTER_NewStart = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the WHICHC() function to find the first variable in a list of variables that equals a specific value.  If none have it then the result is zero.

```
FILTER_NewStart=0 ne whichc('New Start',of GAP1-GAP5);
```

FIND() is for locating a specific substring in a longer string and so cannot work on many variables at once.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom whichc() is a good idea, whereas it doesn't work if GAP1-GAP5 just contain but not equal to 'New Start'. find() would be a better anwser in this situation.